# User Authentication With Flutter API

Tags: laravel, flutter

I got my backend with Laravel and My Api looks like this :

```
Route::apiresource('/user','App\Http\Controllers\api\UserController');
```

And this is my UserController :

```
    <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $user = DB::table('users')->get();
        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

I want to know how can I check if the email and a password in a Flutter screen match my DB records when I hit login button.

This is what I've done so far now in My Flutter :

```
    Future<User> fetchUser() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    if(response.body.isNotEmpty) {
    json.decode(response.body); 
}
    return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load user');
  }
}
```

And of course ,I got my form with 2 inputs Email and password .

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I think you want to authenticate your user in the api. [This page of the documentation is very easy to understand](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication). If the user credentials match, you could return the user and create a token with [laravel sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/master/sanctum) or [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport) for the further requests for example :

```php
// With laravel santum
if(Auth::attempt($signInRequest->only(['email', 'password']), true))
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $token = $user->createToken($signInRequest->input('device_name'))->plainTextToken;
    return response()->json([
        'user'  => $user,
        'token' => $token
    ]);
}
return response()->json(['message' => 'Auth failed'], 401);
```